# jquery modify a particular li element only knowing its position in the list

Tags: jquery, css, web

I have a simple list:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I need to modify one of the li elements, all I know is it's position in the list, for example 2 which would be the 3rd li element). How can I add a class to it by only knowing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), which takes a specified index (0-based) as an argument:

```
$("ul li").eq(2).addClass("yourClass");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8vXU4/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Or inline:

```
$("ul li:eq(2)").html("Add some content")
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.eq` function to specify wich index you want:

```
$('ul').children().eq(2)
```

will point to the third item (indexes start at 0, so 2 is the third)

Answer (score 0):

try this

***HTML***

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
</ul>
```

***JS***

```
$('ul').children().eq(2).addClass('newclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of the following will return you that 2nd `<li>` element.

1. `$('ul li:eq(3)')`
2. `$('ul>li:eq(3)')`
3. `$('ul li').eq(3)`
4. `$('ul>li').eq(3)`
5. `$('ul li').filter(function() {
       return $(this).index() == 3;
   })`
6. `$('ul>li').filter(function() {
       return $(this).index() == 3;
   })`